# Getting html response instead of json rasa x server mode (docker)

Tags: docker, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

I created the rasa x server in server mode using docker-compose (link, https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/install/docker-compose). I want to get intent and entities so I am hitting this URL from postman (https://2286950d1621.jp.ngrok.io/model/parse) with text. But I'm getting an HTML response instead of a JSON response.

Docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.4"

x-database-credentials: &database-credentials
  DB_HOST: "db"
  DB_PORT: "5432"
  DB_USER: "${DB_USER:-admin}"
  DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
  DB_LOGIN_DB: "${DB_LOGIN_DB:-rasa}"

x-rabbitmq-credentials: &rabbitmq-credentials
  RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbit"
  RABBITMQ_USERNAME: "user"
  RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}

x-redis-credentials: &redis-credentials
  REDIS_HOST: "redis"
  REDIS_PORT: "6379"
  REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
  REDIS_DB: "1"

x-duckling-credentials: &duckling-credentials
  RASA_DUCKLING_HTTP_URL: "http://duckling:8000"

x-rasax-credentials: &rasax-credentials
  RASA_X_HOST: "http://rasa-x:5002"
  RASA_X_USERNAME: ${RASA_X_USERNAME:-admin}
  RASA_X_PASSWORD: ${RASA_X_PASSWORD:-}
  RASA_X_TOKEN: ${RASA_X_TOKEN}
  JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
  RASA_USER_APP: "http://app:5055"
  RASA_PRODUCTION_HOST: "http://rasa-production:5005"
  RASA_WORKER_HOST: "http://rasa-worker:5005"
  RASA_TOKEN: ${RASA_TOKEN}

x-rasa-credentials: &rasa-credentials
  <<: *rabbitmq-credentials
  <<: *rasax-credentials
  <<: *database-credentials
  <<: *redis-credentials
  <<: *duckling-credentials
  RASA_TOKEN: ${RASA_TOKEN}
  RASA_MODEL_PULL_INTERVAL: 10
  RABBITMQ_QUEUE: "rasa_production_events"
  RASA_TELEMETRY_ENABLED: ${RASA_TELEMETRY_ENABLED:-true}

x-rasa-services: &default-rasa-service
  restart: always
  image: "rasa/rasa:${RASA_VERSION}-full"
  volumes:
      - ./.config:/.config
  expose:
    - "5005"
  command: >
    x
    --no-prompt
    --production
    --config-endpoint http://rasa-x:5002/api/config?token=${RASA_X_TOKEN}
    --port 5005
    --jwt-method HS256
    --jwt-secret ${JWT_SECRET}
    --auth-token '${RASA_TOKEN}'
    --enable-api
    --cors "*"
  depends_on:
    - rasa-x
    - rabbit
    - redis

services:
  rasa-x:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/rasa-x:${RASA_X_VERSION}"
    expose:
      - "5002"
    volumes:
      - ./models:/app/models
      - ./environments.yml:/app/environments.yml
      - ./credentials.yml:/app/credentials.yml
      - ./endpoints.yml:/app/endpoints.yml
      - ./logs:/logs
      - ./auth:/app/auth
    environment:
      <<: *database-credentials
      <<: *rasa-credentials
      SELF_PORT: "5002"
      DB_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE:-rasa}"
      RASA_MODEL_DIR: "/app/models"
      PASSWORD_SALT: ${PASSWORD_SALT}
      RABBITMQ_QUEUE: "rasa_production_events"
      RASA_X_USER_ANALYTICS: "0"
      SANIC_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT: "3600"
      RUN_DATABASE_MIGRATION_AS_SEPARATE_SERVICE: "true"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db-migration:
    command: ["python", "-m", "rasax.community.services.db_migration_service"]
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/rasa-x:${RASA_X_VERSION}"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8000/health || kill 1"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 2s
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      <<: *database-credentials
      RUN_DATABASE_MIGRATION_AS_SEPARATE_SERVICE: "true"
    depends_on:
      - db

  rasa-production:
    <<: *default-rasa-service
    environment:
      <<: *rasa-credentials
      RASA_ENVIRONMENT: "production"
      DB_DATABASE: "tracker"
      MPLCONFIGDIR: "/tmp/.matplotlib"
      RASA_MODEL_SERVER: "http://rasa-x:5002/api/projects/default/models/tags/production"

  rasa-worker:
    <<: *default-rasa-service
    environment:
      <<: *rasa-credentials
      RASA_ENVIRONMENT: "worker"
      DB_DATABASE: "worker_tracker"
      MPLCONFIGDIR: "/tmp/.matplotlib"
      RASA_MODEL_SERVER: "http://rasa-x:5002/api/projects/default/models/tags/production"

  app:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/rasa-x-demo:${RASA_X_DEMO_VERSION}"
    expose:
      - "5055"
    depends_on:
      - rasa-production

  db:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/postgresql:11.9.0"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USER:-admin}"
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE:-rasa}"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/bitnami/postgresql

  rabbit:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.9"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbit"
      RABBITMQ_USERNAME: "user"
      RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
      RABBITMQ_DISK_FREE_LIMIT: "{mem_relative, 0.1}"
    expose:
      - "5672"

  duckling:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/duckling:0.1.6.4"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    command: ["duckling-example-exe", "--no-access-log", "--no-error-log"]

  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/nginx:${RASA_X_VERSION}"
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
      - "443:8443"
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/opt/bitnami/certs
      - ./terms:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/terms
    depends_on:
      - rasa-x
      - rasa-production
      - app

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/redis:6.0.8"
    environment:
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hit the Rasa Open Source server specifically, add `/core` to the endpoint -- so here:  `https://2286950d1621.jp.ngrok.io/core/model/parse`

The `/core` tells the nginx proxy which service to send your request to. If you want to hit the Rasa X api, you should add `/api`.

What you are seeing currently is the Rasa X UI response, which is the default container (which is why you can log into the UI on the base url directly)

Comment: thankyou, it's working. Please share documentation if you have.